# Meaning of '' amount of something ''

Tags: meaning

I used ''amount of product'' in two same sentences . I wonder if thees sentences may have two diffrent meaning.

> He  demanded large amount of product. ( product in large quantity )
>
> He demanded large amount of product .  (big part of product )

Answer (score 1):

It depends what the "product" is. Is it something you can *count*, such as individual items? Or is it something you would *measure*, such as a liquid?

If you wanted to refer to a large quantity of a *countable* product you should really say:

> He demanded a large *number* of bottles.

If you wanted to refer to a large quantity of a *measurable* product, you could say:

> He demanded a large *amount* of water.

or

> He demanded a large *quantity* of water.

The term "quantity" is to describe the *aggregated number* or *total* for *any* kind of product.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to ask is whether you can use that same wording to mean both an absolute large quantity (such as tonnes of something) or a relative large quantity (a large share, such as 80%).

In both cases, you need an indefinite article (*a*) before 'large'. However, there is a difference in how you should word the rest of it depending on the meaning:

> He demanded a large amount of product.

This means he demanded **lots** of the item, a large quantity in an absolute sense.

> He demanded a large amount of **the** product.

This means he demanded a large share of some specific product or collection of product.

---

By the way, *product* isn't a mass noun in most everyday uses, and your phrasing makes it a mass noun. However, it is a mass noun when used to refer to haircare products - you can say "gosh, he uses a lot of product in his hair" to indicate that you think he uses a lot of hair mousse, spray, gel or whatever. So you appear to be suggesting that someone demanded a lot of haircare product.